Is it possible to access a variable's value via an index in a Datadog Dashboard
I have some variables in a dashboard. Let's just say it is $CONTROLLER with two values IndividualController and CompanyController.
I'm trying to have charts that show each individually but then also a table with both. I would prefer not to have to set any more variables as this dashboard already has a lot so I am trying to see if I can get more out of the variables by setting something like $CONTROLLER.value.0 or $CONTROLLER.value[0] or $CONTROLLER[0] to access the individual values at that index. I have tried each of those examples which (obviously) didn't work.
Just to be clear the full query value would look something like this: @payload.controller:$CONTROLLER[0] for one chart and then @payload.controller:$CONTROLLER[1] for the other and then the last chart would just be @pyload.controller:$CONTROLLER <-- this last one does work just fine, it is breaking them out I am trying to achieve.
Is there a way to handle this in Datadog?
